# Image download null reference exception

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to create an image downloader. Basically it is supposed to go through a website and download all of the images. The error I get is in the first line of the foreach loop, `System.NullReferenceException`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
    browser.Navigate("http://www.mysite.com");
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    HtmlElementCollection imgCollection = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    foreach (HtmlElement img in imgCollection)
    {
        string url = img.FirstChild.GetAttribute("src");
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/')));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
img.FirstChild.GetAttribute("src");
```

to that:

```
img.GetAttribute("src");
```

Comment: Now after fixing that i get this error `'System.Net.WebException'`at the next line, `webClient.DownloadFile(url,url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/')));
`

Comment: well what is stored in url?

Comment: lets say i put google.com as the url, it should download the image on the homepage

Comment: umm.. ok lets say a website that does? how will it automatically download all the images that are after '/'?

Comment: according to your code you have a loop that iterate the website for each image which is under the root:
I.e: www.gooogle.com/mypic1.png, www.gooogle.com/mypic2.png and etc.
according to the example your code seems to try and download mypic1.png from www.google.com afterwards mypic2.png
What is the question here?

Comment: oh, i didnt even know that. Well its not supposed to do that, do you know how I can change it so that it will download all images regardless of their names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33649/discussion-between-fjam-and-g-y)

Answer (score 3):

`<img>` elements do not have children.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 string url = img.FirstChild.GetAttribute("src");
```

to

```
 string url = img.GetAttribute("src");
```

as img doesn't have childrens.